# error in using animation

Tags: android, animation

I'm using fade in and fade out for my little game

say there are 10 images i want to blink(=fade out and fade in right away).

on Click of an image, the image blinks.

But when I click img a, b, c, d right after each other,

the one blinked before blinks again

so like

key press                  |        blink

a...................a

b................. a&b

c................ a,b,c

d ................ a,b,c,d

But when I press the images with term(maybe like a second or so), this does no happen

What should I do? I'm using xmls like

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
  android:fromAlpha="0.1"
  android:toAlpha="1.0"
  android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

help!

------code added

```
    private void col(int a) {
    B[a].startAnimation(animFadeOut);
    B[a].setBackgroundColor(col[arr[a]]);
    if (arr[a] > 8)
        B[a].setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    if (arr[a] <= 8)
        B[a].setTextColor(0xff000000);
    B[a].startAnimation(animFadeIn);
}
```

this col() method is the only place I used animation

I double checked that this method is not repeatedly called,

saying that a,b,c blinks at the call of col(c)(in the example above)

Comment: post your code. We know the animation itself works, it how it's applied to the objects that seems to be the trouble.

Comment: I think Jim is right. If you have an Animation object as member of your class, you could face this kind of issue. Set a specific Animation object for each ImageView.

Comment: @Groco can you tell me more specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I say in my comment:
"I think Jim is right. If you have an Animation object as member of your class, you could face this kind of issue. Set a specific Animation object for each ImageView."

Now that you have posted your code, I can see that you use `animFadeOut` to set animation to all your views.
If you declare a local Animation variable in your col method rather than use a Class variable, your problem could be solved.
Sharing the same Animation object with several views could lead to an unexpected behavior.

Try that code:

```
 private void col(int a) {
  B[a].startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.my_animation));
  B[a].setBackgroundColor(col[arr[a]]);
  if (arr[a] > 8)
    B[a].setTextColor(0xffffffff);
  if (arr[a] <= 8)
    B[a].setTextColor(0xff000000);
  B[a].startAnimation(animFadeIn);
}
```

Comment: Well im such a newbie at programming and I tried  to make an instance of the animation but it still doesnt work. Can you tell me more precisely? What ive done is like making an array of animations referring to those  xml files.. But this doesnt work.... help me out plz

Comment: Thanks a lot that works just exactly the way I want.

Comment: Nice!!! So that was because you use the same animation object with all your views.

Comment: I think so. I dont understand what's going on in there but now Ive got the technique Thanksz

Comment: Ive got a question though, can't you play the animation anytime you want after B[i].setAnimation(animation)?? it takes quite a time to attach the animation everytime I call the method.

Comment: Once the animation is created and attached to the view by `startAnimation` or `setAnimation`, you can try `animation.start`. In this way, you have to store each animation you create. A crappy way is to use `setTag` method of a View...